# how to find a word in an external website with php

Tags: php, find, cpu-word

How I can find a specific word in a external page using PHP? This page is protected by a login area. Is it possible to do something?

```
<?php 
$v = file_get_contents("http://it.website.com");
echo substr_count($v, 'web'); // number of occurences

//or single match

echo substr_count($v, ' abcd ');
?>
```

My problem is to pass the login automatically..

Login form:

```
<form name="login" action="/login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check(this);">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Email o Nome utente</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="user_email" class="form-control input-lg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" value="" name="user_pass" class="form-control input-lg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Accedi" name="login" class="btn btn-primary pull-right push-bottom" data-loading-text="Loading...">
        <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="checklogin" id="login">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is extremely unclear. What do you mean by the last line?

Comment: Way too complicated for a simple answer here. (And I didn't even see the fact that you can't login before I said that.)

Comment: method will depend on type of log in

Comment: i've an account and i login normally...but i need to develop an automatic script that do this for me. There isnt a captcha or other controll..only password and username

Comment: can you post an example of the login form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code snippet (PHP 5+ needed, for older versions ask please).
It sends a POST request as it is done when the *Accedi* button is pressed:

```
$url = 'http://it.website.com/login.php';
$para = array(
    'user_email' => 'myname@example.com',
    'user_pass'  => 'MySuperSecretPassword',
    'mode'       => 'checklogin', // the hidden field in the form
);
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($para),
    )
);
$ctxt  = stream_context_create($opts);
$page = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctxt);
if ($page !== false) {
    // $page contains the page returned by the web server
    echo substr_count($page, ' abcd ');
    echo substr_count($page, 'web');
}
```

Note: The **user_email**, **user_pass**, the hidden **mode** fields and the url part **/login.php** are taken from the <form>…</form> code. Maybe it is a good idea to have a look at the **check(this);** function.

Comment: function check(form)
        {
            if (form.user_email.value.search(/\S/) == -1)
            {
                alert("Per favore inserisci la tua email.");
                form.user_email.select();
                return false;
            }
            if (form.user_pass.value.search(/\S/) == -1)
            {
                alert("Per favore inserisci la tua password");
                form.user_pass.select();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

Comment: The function obviously just checks mandatory field contents. It does not modify them at all. So, the above example should be ok with that.